# Normal standard variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, normal-distribution, density-function

Suppose $X \sim N(3,4^2)$ and let $Y =(X-3)/4$. Prove that $Y \sim N(0,1^2)$ as follows: Find a formula expressing $F_{Y}$ in terms of $F_{X}$. Find a formula for $f_{Y}$. Show that your formula for $f_{Y}$ agrees with the pdf of a standard normal random variable except at most at a set of measure zero. It then follows that Y has the same distribution as a standard normal random variable.

Just a quick question, $Y$'s pdf will agree with the pdf of a standard normal variable everywhere right? If not, what is the set of measure $0$ for which the pdf of $Y$ and the pdf of the standard normal variable are not equal?

Comment: You know, if random variable $Z$ has density $f_Z$ with respect to Lebesque measure $\lambda$, then every function $g \in \{ f: f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \}$ such that $\lambda(\{ x \in \mathbb R : g(x) \neq f_Z(x) \}) = 0$ is also a density of $Z$. Long story short: Density is determined up to the set of measure $0$. If we change our density on the set of $\lambda-$ measure $0$, it's still density of the same variable, even when we set negative values on that set of measure $0$. It's simple because Lebesque integral is "blind" when facing sets of $\lambda-$ measure $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method of proof is to express $F_Y$ in terms of $F_X$ and then to differentiate $F_Y$ to obtain $f_Y$, then yes, your density $f_Y$ will agree everywhere with the standard normal density; the set where they differ will be empty (which of course has measure zero).

Comment: Thank you! But why do you say "If ...". If you use some other method this is not true?